# Alpine Add Package from Edge repository

Tags: repository, alpine-linux, package-managers

If I'm using Alpine 3.8, how can I add a specific package from the Alpine Edge repository? Is this even supported? There is no equivalent of backports, from what I can see.

I want to add the new version of this: https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/edge/community/armhf/librdkafka

And not the older version in the 3.8 repo:
https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/v3.8/community/s390x/librdkafka

Comment: To update [valiano's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52903112/10393488), the Alpine Edge repository url should now be `--repository=https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/community`

Answer (score 129, accepted):

You could specify the exact repo to apk, using the `--repository` parameter.
In your case:

```
apk add librdkafka --repository=https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/community
```

Comment: I needed to use `--repository=http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/main` (without the `x86_64`, because apk seems to add that itself).

Comment: For installing the newest librdfkafka (currently 1.0.1) from edge use community `--repository=http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/community` instead

Comment: Thanks! I was able to install [skopeo](https://github.com/containers/skopeo) in the recent version 1.0.0 (r1) with you help and this line:
`apk add skopeo --repository=http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/community`

Comment: For packages found/shown under https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/edge/testing/x86_64/, what worked for me was `apk add package-name --repository=https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/testing`

Comment: If you have /etc/apk/repositories file, and there are different repos listed on top, even if you add the --repository flag for apk add, the repos in the /etc file will overwrite your preference.
I removed the already existing locations, added the repo version I needed and it worked.

Answer (score 43):

You can also add the repo:

```bash
echo "@testing https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/testing" >> /etc/apk/repositories
```

and reference it with apk via `@testing`. Example:

```bash
apk add package-name@testing
```

Comment: Excellent, please consider replacing http:// by https://

Answer (score 5):

Edge repository may be enabled permanently. Just do the following:

```sh
sed -i '/edge/s/^#//' /etc/apk/repositories
```

Comment: Your sed command assumes the edge repositories are already included in the file which is not the case in alpine 3.15. An updated command that replaces the repositories to edge is `sed -i 's|v3\.\d*|edge|' /etc/apk/repositories`