# Alpine Docker image FROM python:3.x-alpine3.x uses different package version for Python than stated

Tags: python-3.x, docker, dockerfile, alpine-linux

If I build the simpliest docker image based on Alpine that includes Python:

```
FROM python:3.7-alpine3.9
```

I can successfully enter it and verify that the installed version is 3.7:

```
/ # python --version
Python 3.7.3
/ # python3 --version
Python 3.7.3
```

However if I install some packages that require Python3, for example`python3-dev` (that is required by other packages) or Python3 itself, Alpine does not use version 3.7 but uses 3.6 for some reason that I don't understand:

```
/ # apk add python3-dev
(1/3) Installing pkgconf (1.6.0-r0)
(2/3) Installing python3 (3.6.8-r2)
(3/3) Installing python3-dev (3.6.8-r2)
Executing busybox-1.29.3-r10.trigger
OK: 108 MiB in 38 packages
```

`printenv` also shows that (during the docker image build) version 3.7.x is used but package system does not reflect this. Excerpt:

```
PYTHON_VERSION=3.7.3
```

I see [here](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/packages?name=python3&branch=v3.9) there's Python 3.6 as a default version for all Alpine versions up to 3.9. Python 3.7 is available for the "edge" only.

I also found answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52899227) which doesn't work either:

```
# apk add python3 --repository=http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/main
(1/1) Installing python3 (3.6.8-r2)
```

Python 3.6 is installed. However if I use the simpliest Alpine without Python `FROM alpine:3.9` and use the same command, **Python 3.7 is installed**:

```
# apk add python3 --repository=http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/main
<TRIMMED_TEXT>
(11/11) Installing python3 (3.7.3-r0)
```

How can I tell the package manager in `python:3.7-alpine3.9` to use Python 3.7 instead of Python 3.6?

Comment: Did the answer solve your problem? Please close this, then. Otherwise, I'll try to help you further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you remove the ([virtual](https://github.com/docker-library/python/blob/ce69fc6369feb8ec757b019035ddad7bac20562c/3.7/alpine3.9/Dockerfile#L87)) `.python-rundeps` package beforehand, the installation will work as you intend it.

```
FROM python:3.7-alpine3.9

RUN \
    apk update \
    && apk del .python-rundeps \
    && apk add --repository=http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/main \
        python3-dev=3.7.3-r0
```

Building this image results in:

```
...
(12/13) Installing python3 (3.7.3-r0)
...
```

Answer (score -2):

Do you need python version 3.7? You can use version 3.6, It exists: `https://hub.docker.com/_/python/?tab=tags&page=3`

```
FROM python:3.6-alpine3.9
```

or

```
FROM python:3.6.8-alpine
FROM python:3.6-alpine
FROM python:3.6.8-alpine3.9
```