# How to install MariaDB ODBC drivers in Docker/Alpine

Tags: docker, mariadb, pyodbc, alpine-linux

I see that Alpine supports in its Docker container a MariaDB ODBC Driver as listed [here](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/edge/testing/x86/mariadb-connector-odbc). I need to install it to be used with `pyodbc`.

What is the `Dockerfile` command that installs the driver in the image?

Something along the lines of `RUN apk add mariadb-connector-odbc`
?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My clean install of Alpine had an `/etc/apk/repositories` file that looked like

```
#/media/cdrom/apks
http://mirror.reenigne.net/alpine/v3.13/main
#http://mirror.reenigne.net/alpine/v3.13/community
#http://mirror.reenigne.net/alpine/edge/main
#http://mirror.reenigne.net/alpine/edge/community
#http://mirror.reenigne.net/alpine/edge/testing
```

With that setup

```
apk add mariadb-connector-odbc
```

failed. However, after uncommenting the last line …

```
#/media/cdrom/apks
http://mirror.reenigne.net/alpine/v3.13/main
#http://mirror.reenigne.net/alpine/v3.13/community
#http://mirror.reenigne.net/alpine/edge/main
#http://mirror.reenigne.net/alpine/edge/community
http://mirror.reenigne.net/alpine/edge/testing
```

… the same command succeeded

```
localhost:~# apk add mariadb-connector-odbc
fetch http://mirror.reenigne.net/alpine/edge/testing/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
(1/3) Installing readline (8.1.0-r0)
(2/3) Installing unixodbc (2.3.9-r1)
(3/3) Installing mariadb-connector-odbc (3.1.11-r0)
Executing busybox-1/32/1-r6.trigger
OK: 903 MiB in 146 packages
localhost:~# ls -la /usr/lib/mariadb
total 536
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root         4096 May 14 22:43 .
drwxr-xr-x    6 root     root         4096 May 14 22:43 ..
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root       537856 Jan  6 02:39 libmaodbc.so
```

Comment: I'm getting this, and I cannot figure out what's this dependency: `#13 0.471 fetch http://mirror.reenigne.net/alpine/edge/testing/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
#13 0.909 ERROR: unsatisfiable constraints:
#13 0.915   so:libodbcinst.so.2 (missing):
#13 0.915     required by: mariadb-connector-odbc-3.1.11-r0[so:libodbcinst.so.2]`

Comment: `libodbcinst.so.*` is usually installed as part of unixodbc, which was included as a dependency of the `mariadb-connector-odbc` package (see `(2/3)` in the answer). You might try `apk add unixodbc` before trying to install the driver itself. (Forgive me, but I have no practical experience with Alpine Linux in the docker context. My testing is on a VirtualBox VM.)

Comment: This [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52899227/alpine-add-package-from-edge-repository) might also help, in order to get a specific package from the Alpine Edge repo.